# Split python pandas use list

Tags: python, pandas, split

python 3.6.5

the list is

```
a_l=['12','20','20','150']
```

the pandas dataframe df is

```
print(df)

typeid

0 132
1 124
2 1245
3 145
4 1574
...
...
...
200 487
201 154
```

i want split dataframe  like this：

```
df.iloc[0:11],df.iloc[12:19],df.iloc[20:19],df.iloc[52:149]
```

i try

```
   for i in a_l:
       print(a_l.index(i),i)

out:
   0 12
   1 20
   1 20
   3 152
```

'20' index is  duplicated

Comment: Where did `c_l` come from? You are missing out a lot of information required to replicate what you tried. Please update the question!

Comment: Why `df.iloc[20:19]` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if the problem is that the index for your value '20' is both times 1 it is because `index()` returns at the first occurrence of the value you're looking for. Why not simply iterate by index? 
`for i in range(len(c_i))`?

Comment: df.iloc[20:19] i want get start index 20 get 19 rows

Comment: @菜合馍馍 the slicing works with rows indexes. If you try to run your code you'll see that when you call `df.iloc[20:19]` you get an empty dataframe. it's not by number of rows. If you want 19 rows from index 20 you should do `df.iloc[20:39]`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only a duplicate of the list value, then I suggest the following.

```
a_l = ['12','20','20','150']
aaa = list(set(a_l))#['20', '12', '150']

for i in aaa:
   print(aaa.index(i), i)
```

You can apply a set and get only unique values.
Since you need indexes, then convert the set to a list.
Note that the sequence of values becomes different. If this is important, then see below.

```
rrr = set([int(item) for item in a_l])#First, we convert the values to an int number and make a set from the list.
ttt = [str(item) for item in rrr]#Converting values back from int to string
print(ttt)#['12', '20', '150']
```